# JWT Authorization in .net Core - communicate with OAuth server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

I start building new application with JWT authorization. Our team already have OAuth 2 server written in java, so my target is: check key with public key. 
But I don't know how to do it. If I use .net identity I have to use entity framework but I use only Cassandra as a database.

How I can implement it without using EF? Do you know any tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any ASP.NET Core stuff. A simple approach would be:

Nu-get the Packages

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt,
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
```

Set up some validation parameters:

```
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    RequireExpirationTime = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    IssuerSigningKeys = keys, // Your public keys.
    ValidAudience = "my valid audience",
    ValidIssuer = "my valid issuer"
}
```

Call ValidateToken to get a `ClaimsPrincipal` with claims and stuff.
`token` is your JWT string, e.g. parsed from Authorization HTTP header.

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
```

Using `JsonWebKeySet` from the above `IdentityModel.Tokens` package, you can automagically obtain keys from an OpenID Connect configuration:

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/master/source/IdentityModel.Shared/Jwt/JsonWebKeySet.cs

Comment: If i decidet to use blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/… how I can set only validate token by publish key in local instance?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few Microsoft (and other) documents available (make sure you are looking at documents relevant to the version that you are working with!) - googling will find them pretty easily, but EF is certainly not required as seen below.

> No identity or user information is managed by the app directly. Instead, it will get all the user information it needs directly from the JWT token that authenticates a caller.
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/

Here is a simple example for version 1.1
https://github.com/williamhallatt/aspnet-core-webapi-jwt-auth-example

and the same example for 2.0
https://github.com/williamhallatt/aspnet-core-webapi-jwt-auth-example/tree/dotnecore2.0